# Конвертация UTF-8 в UCS

Tags: java, строки, utf-8, кодировка

Необходимо прочитать строку из файла и конвертировать ее из UTF-8 в UTF-16LE вручную. Для этого, как я понимаю, нужно сначала ее перевести в UCS. По заданию необходимо сделать это вручную. Гуглил, но ничего толкового не нашел, может, правда, проглазел. 
Кто-нибудь может подсказать алгоритм для перевода в UCS?

Comment: Может Вам сначала требуется перевести UTF-8 в UTF-32? Формат UTF-8 [описан тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), а формат UTF-16LE, с примерами преобразования в UTF-32 и обратно - [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о `BMP` (`Basic multilingual plane`), то `UTF-16` фактически становится `UCS-2`, и можно просто прочитать `code point` из `UTF-8` и закодировать его сразу в символ `UTF-16`. Если это `BMP`, то размер символа не превысит `16 бит`. Если же нужно обрабатывать всю таблицу юникода, сперва нужно закодировать в `UTF-32`, просто прочитав значение `code point` из `UTF-8`, а потом `UTF-32` перекодировать в `UTF-16`, для символов больше, чем `0xD7FF` создавая суррогатные пары.

Алгоритм действий такой:

1. Читаем первый символ
2. Узнаём длину `code point`:

   ```
   constexpr const uint8_t utf8_length_data[256] = {
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1
   };

   inline constexpr uint8_t utf8DecodeLength(uint8_t c) {
       return utf8_length_data[c];
   }
   ```
3. Узнаём маску значения для первого байта (для остальных всегда `0x3f`):

   ```
   static constexpr inline uint8_t utf8DecodeMask(uint8_t codePointLength) {
       switch (codePointLength) {
           case 1: return 0x7f; break;
           case 2: return 0x1f; break;
           case 3: return 0x0f; break;
           case 4: return 0x07; break;
           case 5: return 0x03; break;
           case 6: return 0x01; break;
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. Вычисляем значение `code point`, обрабатывая по байтово `codePointLength` символов исходной строки.

   ```
   static constexpr inline char32_t utf8Decode(string str, size_t offset, uint8_t codePointLength, uint8_t mask) {
       char32_t ret = str[offset] & mask;
       for (uint8_t c = 1; c < codePointLength; ++c) {
           ret <<= 6; ret |= (str[offset + c] & 0x3f);
       }
       return ret;
   }
   ```
5. Если возвращаем `UCS-2`, то просто отбрасываем два старших байта и пишем в результат два младших.
6. Если возвращаем полный `UTF-16`, то проверяем, если значение меньше или равно `0xD7FF`, сразу пишем его в результат, в противном случае - создаём суррогатную пару из двух символов `UTF-16`, это просто, можно глянуть в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5).

P.S. Прошу прощения за код на C++, плохо знаю Java.

Comment: Почему у меня отступы перед кодом не работали?

Comment: Это особенность редактора. Если вы добавляете код в список, необходимо использовать восемь пробелов вместо четырех.

Answer (score 0):

Читаешь строки из файлового потока и кодируешь байты из твоей строки в UTF-8 в UTF -16LE и создаешь новую строку. Новая строка будет в кодировке UTF - 16LE.
Пример смены кодировки строки:
`String g2 = "text in UTF-8";
 String decode =  new String(g2.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));`